# JHipster application in docker container cannot be accessed on host network, cannot communicate with other containers on non-host network

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I am trying to deploy my JHipster microservices and registry in docker containers on my OS X development machine.

I deploy the registry using more or less the default docker-compose configuration JHipster provides out of the box:

```
version: '2'
services:
    jhipster-registry:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.1.0
        volumes:
            - ./central-server-config:/central-config
        # When run with the "dev" Spring profile, the JHipster Registry will
        # read the config from the local filesystem (central-server-config directory)
        # When run with the "prod" Spring profile, it will read the configuration from a Git repository
        # See https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/#registry_app_configuration
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native
            - SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/localhost-config/
            # - GIT_URI=https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/
            # - GIT_SEARCH_PATHS=central-config
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
```

When I deploy my microservices using `docker run`, however, one of two things happens:

If I publish the port I want to make the microservice available on using `-p 8080:8080` so I can access it through the browser, I can reach it but the microservice cannot find the registry.

```
Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://jhipster-registry:8761/config/clientaggregator/dev,twilio": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Meanwhile, I can view the  pages the registry serves fine.

I can fix this by adding "--network=host" when starting the microservice. However, when I do that this apparently overrides the native-to-host port mapping and the microservice cannot be reached from the browser.

What's more bizarre is that about a week ago I was using the exact same configuration, which worked fine.

[image]

If I run my application outside of a docker container, it connects to the registry fine. If I create a different container, or connect to the microservice container and access the configuration url via curl, I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is trying to locate the registry using the name `jhipster-registry` as a host name. To be able to do that, you need to have your registry and app added to a docker network.

First create the network using:

```
docker network create my-network
```

Update the compose file by giving the container a name and adding it to the network create:

```
version: '2'
services:
    jhipster-registry:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.1.0
        volumes:
            - ./central-server-config:/central-config
        # When run with the "dev" Spring profile, the JHipster Registry will
        # read the config from the local filesystem (central-server-config directory)
        # When run with the "prod" Spring profile, it will read the configuration from a Git repository
        # See https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/#registry_app_configuration
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev,native
            - SECURITY_USER_PASSWORD=admin
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_NATIVE_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/localhost-config/
            # - GIT_URI=https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/
            # - GIT_SEARCH_PATHS=central-config
        ports:
            - 8761:8761
        networks:
            - my-network
        container_name: jhipster-registry


networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

When running your application specify the network:

```
docker run --network=my-network ...
```

Now your application can communicate with the registry using `jhipster-registry` as a hostname.

Comment: And I can't access the container from my browser.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku can you provide the output for docker ps?

Comment: `fae11e00e397        clientaggregator             "/bin/sh -c 'echo ..."   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        5701/udp, 0.0.0.0:32769->8081/tcp   wizardly_pasteur1`

Comment: `80c4b4ab65b0        jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.1.0   "java -Djava.secur..."   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes        0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp              docker_jhipster-registry_1`

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku what port are u using to access from the browser?

Comment: The container should be available at 8080.